# Use $(document).ready() to allow function execution

Tags: jquery

I'm, let's say, new to jquery. I've stumbled across a quite interesting problem.
I`ve page with text ( text and images ) and button for next. Clicking the button has to make 2 things first go to next element and call loadNext. No problem so far, but the loadNext procces some info from the next element. It must be executed after all the content is loaded.

So how to put the ready check inside the click function - 
$('#next').click(loadNext);

```
$('#next').click(function () {
   loadNext();
});
```

This doesn`t work. Nevertheless jquery version used is 1.3.2 because of Greasemonkey problem with the later versions (problem with //@require).

Can you give any suggestion what to do.

Comment: can you give some more info. when you click next div , what should happen exactly. Can you provide the complete html and what functionality you are expecting on the click.

Comment: The complete code is a kind of a mystery - lots and lots of jquery generating a lot of tables. It`s not my code. Functionality: 1. I click; 2. new element appear; 3. loadNext catch part of the text, process, and send to db. I forgot to mention that when page is initialized there is no button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the button until the content is loaded:

```
<button id="next" disabled="disabled" />

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#next').removeAttr('disabled').click(function () {
       $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       loadNext();
    });
});
```

Comment: If there is no button initially don't add it until after the content is loaded.